# SQL insert a User role

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, insert

I have the following users/roles table structure in a database. And I want to set a role (for example, "CUSTOMER" for a user). So that the role id will be inserted into the User_Roles table as well as the appropriate user id. What is the correct SQL query for that?

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO user_roles (user_id, role_id)
SELECT users.id, 3
FROM users
WHERE users.id = 1
```

Is there a better way to do that?

```
---- Users Table ---------
ID | UserName | Password
 1 | SomeUser | *****
--------------------------

---- Roles Table ---------
ID | Role
 1 | CUSTOMER
 2 | ADMIN
--------------------------

---- User_Roles Table ---------
UserID | RoleID
     1 |      1
     1 |      2
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
INSERT INTO user_roles (user_id, role_id)
    VALUES ( 1, 3 );
```

If you want to do it by name:

```
INSERT INTO user_roles (user_id, role_id)
    SELECT 1, r.role_id
    FROM roles r
    WHERE r.name = 'CUSTOMER';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the following code:

```
INSERT INTO User_Roles VALUES(2,(SELECT id FROM Roles WHERE Role = "CUSTOMER"));
```

Where the number "2" represent the id of the user you want to give the  role to.